# How to iteratively run a SAS procedure with different subsets of data?

Tags: sas

I would like to repeatedly run `PROC REG` with different subsets of an existing SAS dataset.  Here's a simple example dataset:

```
DATA data_main;
  input trt depth year response;
  cards;
1 1 2014 1.1
1 2 2014 1.2
2 1 2014 1.3
2 2 2014 1.4
1 1 2013 2.2
1 2 2013 2.4
2 1 2013 2.6
2 2 2013 2.8
;
run;
```

For each combination of trt and depth I want to run this procedure, where `current_data` is the current combination of `trt` and `depth`:

```
PROC REG data = current_data;
    model response = year;
run;
```

And I want to capture the regression coefficients and p-values for all iterations in one dataset or text file.

The number of levels of input and trt is much greater in my actual dataset, so I'm trying to avoid manually coding each combination.  Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: BY TRT DEPTH; and use OUTEST= on the proc statement.

Comment: @data_null_ Thanks-- that's perfect.   I was making it way too difficult.

Comment: You can also use `ODS table parameterestimates=want;` to get a table of parameter estimates with p-values.

Comment: @data_null_ Why do you keep posting answers in comments?

Answer (score 1):

Consider running a macro iterating through the combinations of `trt` and `depth`. Below nested loop iteratively re-creates the `current_data` dataset and uses it in regression procedure outputting the corresponding result table. Adjust value ranges in loop limits as needed for all combinations:

```
%macro loopregression;
%do j = 1 %to 2;                 * TRT VALUES;
    %do i = 2013 %to 2014;       * DEPTH VALUES; 
        DATA current_data; 
            SET data_main;  
            if trt = &j;    
            if depth = &i;
        run;

        PROC REG data = current_data noprint outest=results&i&j;;
            model response = year;
        run;
    %end;
%end;
%mend loopregression;

%loopregression;
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I originally tried to use a macro approach but couldn't get it to work. Data_null_'s comment to my post was the simplest solution, but your answer is very helpful because I wanted to learn how to use macros as well.